# Error trying to return char* in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, char, codeblocks

im want to make a function to get te full path of a file from 2 strings, but i got a compiling error

> aviso: el tipo de dato por defecto es ‘int’ en el nombre de tipo [-Wimplicit-int]|

```
char *crearRuta(const *char ruta,const *char nombre){ (error in this line)
char* toReturn;

// Sacamos el nombre completo con la ruta del archivo
toReturn=(char *) malloc(strlen(ruta)+strlen(nombre)+2); // Sump 2, por el '\0'y '/'

//Verifico si el usuario ingreso la '/' final
if (ruta[tmp-1]=='/')
{
    sprintf(toReturn;,"%s%s", ruta, nombre);
}
else
  {
    sprintf(toReturn,"%s/%s", ruta, nombre);
  }
  return toReturn;}


int main(){
char * c=crearRuta("una/direccion","archivo.txt");

return 0;}
```

Comment: Look at that code. Frankly, could you read it? No. Now reformat it and it will immediately be easier for you to debug it.

Comment: you haven't declared tmp.

Comment: If you remove `(error in this line)`, you'll get rid of at least one error.

Answer (score 2):

```
sprintf(toReturn;,"%s%s", ruta, nombre);

                ^
```

error above. You have a typo with the extra `;`.

Comment: feel very stupid. i also see now error in declaration and with temp. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Extra `;` is there

```
sprintf(toReturn;,"%s%s", ruta, nombre);
```

Correct it to

```
 sprintf(toReturn,"%s%s", ruta, nombre);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say you need to clear up your fundamentals first.

char *crearRuta(const *char ruta,const *char nombre){ (error in this line)
char* toReturn;

Just had a glimpse, change it to the following.

```
char *crearRuta(const char *ruta,const char *nombre){ (error in this line)
```

Answer (score -1):

Asterist back or front of data type is very differnce and was trigger an error, 
you should use:

```
const char *var2 , const char *var2
```